# RESTful approach to updating time-related data on resource

Tags: rest, grails

So I have the following resource (expressed as a Grails domain class):

```
class WorkRecord {

  ...

  Date logInTime
  Date logOutTime

  ...

}
```

Now, I'm trying to create a RESTful approach to log into, or out of work through `WorkRecord`. What I'm thinking of is by calling something like,

```
PUT /workrecords/2
```

sending something like (JSON request)

```
{... logInTime: <date> ...}
```

to log in, or change property name to `logOutTime` to log out. This follows the resource oriented approach (I think). However, I really can't trust the client to send the server correct date every time, so I'd like the server to set the log in/out time itself. But then, I can't figure out how the request body should be like. The alternative I can think of right now is do the same `PUT /workrecords/2` to the server with some request like,

```
{... action: 'logIn' ...}
```

which doesn't look very RESTful. How do I go about this?

Comment: /workrecords/2/login and /workrecords/2/logout PUT to those URIs and let the server assign the dates but accept the other information (user, etc) in the body.

Comment: Isn't that not very RESTful, considering login, and logout are not not resources/documents, but actions?

Comment: I'm not going to argue for/against if it's RESTful or not since that is a sliding scale and each extreme has pros/cons. My suggestion addresses your concern, and is RESTful enough. E.g. a resource for login/logout (which I assume has other related info) as it pertains to a workrecord. Yes, those are actions but the data/model/representation/resource you are PUTting is in fact a resource.

Comment: I would consider modeling logins and logouts as resources. That would both resolve your RESTfulness concern and give you a lot of flexibility. In any event, a PUT is reliant on the data from the client being correct. If you need your server to control data, you need a POST.

Comment: @EricStein Excellent point about PUT vs POST.